# Why does my AY-3-8910 sound so distorted?

Tags: arduino, audio, sound, lm386

I'm building a circuit driven by an `Arduino UNO` that controls a `AY-3-8910` programmable sound generator.

The AY has three pins labeled Channel A, B and C.  Each output is an independent sound channel.

I am piping the audio through an `LM386` which then drives a small PC speaker.

When I run a single channel, it sounds pretty good.  But each time I mix another channel, things start getting really distorted.

I've built this on a breadboard in the past and it sounded great so I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time.

Below is a crude schematic of my circuit.  I didn't draw the LM386 because it's the same with or without it and I never used it before.

Any ideas how I can cleanly mix these signals?  I don't remember doing anything in the past other than literally connecting all three channels together.

I can provide more schematics and/or videos or pictures too.  This is driving me nuts.  So I'm hoping someone out there has worked with this sound generator in the past that can provide some insight.

Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftGWXg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The LM386 has differential inputs, how are you hooking it up to the single ended AY-3-8912? Also, the LM386 has some intrinsic gain, you are probably exceeding its rails (the AY-3-8912 outputs a 1V PP square on each channel...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical circuit diagram from the manual shows a 1K resistor to ground and capacitive coupling. Both are necessary. The 10K may also be required.

[image]

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I totally missed that even after scanning the AY datasheet.  Ugh.  Rookie mistake.  Now it sounds great!  Thanks.